# Using residualized predictors outside the linear model context

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution

Can anyone point me towards a good explanation of when a residualized variable in a regression will give you the same answer as using a non-residualized variable with controls?

For instance, say I want to know the effect of a variable $x$ on $y$ and need to control for $a$ and $b$. In a classic linear model framework I can either add $a$ and $b$ as covariates (i.e., control variables) to the model of $y$ on $x$, or I can first regress $x$ on $a$ and $b$, and then use the residuals from this regression (the residualized $x$) to predict $y$. Both will give the same coefficient for $x$.

This works in the linear model case, but does a residualized $x$ give the same coefficient as $x$ with controls for other types of models, e.g., logit models or Poisson models? My own simple simulations suggest they do not (see R code below), but I am trying to understand why, and if residualization can ever be used in place of adding controls outside of the linear model framework. Can anyone point me towards a good explanation?

```
#generate the data
n=10000
set.seed(3345)
a=rnorm(n); b=rnorm(n)
x = .4*a + .4*b*b + rnorm(n)
y = .5*x + .3*a + .3*b*b + rnorm(n)

## LINEAR MODEL ####
#a model with controls gets the right coefficient
summary(lm(y ~ x + a + I(b^2)))
residmod=lm(x ~ a + I(b^2))
x.resid=resid(residmod)
#using a residualized variable gets the same coefficient
summary(lm(y ~ x.resid))

## LOGIT MODEL ####
y=.5*x + .3*a + .3*b*b + rlogis(n)
ydichot=ifelse(y >0, 1, 0)
#a model with controls gets the right coefficient
summary(glm(ydichot ~ x + a + I(b^2), family=binomial))
#using a residualized variable does NOT get the same coefficient
summary(glm(ydichot ~ x.resid, family=binomial))

## POISSON MODEL ####
mu=exp(.5*x + .3*a + .3*b*b)
ycount=rpois(n, mu)
summary(glm(ycount ~ x + a + I(b^2), family=poisson))
#using a residualized variable does NOT get the same coefficient
summary(glm(ycount ~ x.resid, family=poisson))
```

Comment: http://clas.wayne.edu/Multimedia/wurm/files/Wurm%20%26%20Fisicaro%20(2014).pdf I hope this is useful.

Comment: Because the link offered by @Chris looked suspect to one flagger, I inspected it.  It goes to a PDF copy of "What residualizing predictors in regression analyses does (and what it does not do)" by Lee H. Wurm and  Sebastiano A. Fisicaro (J. of Memory and Language 72 (2014) pp 37-48).

Answer (score 2):

Residualization can be used outside the linear framework. For a direct use of residualization on nonlinear probability models, you could consult this paper: http://smx.sagepub.com/content/42/1/286. It explains what residualization does in  nonlinear probability models.

Residualization is also used in nonparametric regression.